# How to explore a package in python

Tags: python

```
import pkg
dir(pkg)
```

such a statement in python won't show all the classes / functions / subpackages in the package pkg because some of them might be loaded just in time.So what is the best way to explore a package in python?

Comment: If you don't have to do it during runtime, simply look at the sourcecode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you try  pydoc

> pydoc package

Is the same as calling the help function but you can do it from the command line,
and of course you can browse to a module, class or function level with the dot notation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `help(pkg)`, or obviously doc if it's available.

Answer (score 2):

Read the source, read the module docs.